# Why does PayPal's Express Checkout fail with no errors?

Tags: php, paypal, express-checkout

PayPal is failing on the first step in checkout.php which is called from JavaScript. I am using the sandbox and have tried running it locally and on a server. I sent a tech. support request explaining the problem but after 3 days I have heard nothing back from them. Blame it on the weather I guess.

The following contains a string of parameters that all seem to be correctly entered. It also contains blank error messages:

nvpstr=&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT=15.00&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION=Sale&RETURNURL=http://jquery.bunkerhill.com/php/orderconfirm.php&CANCELURL=http://jquery.bunkerhill.com/php/cancel.php&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE=USD&REQCONFIRMSHIPPING=0&NOSHIPPING=1&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME0=jQuery-Translator&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT0=15.00&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY0=1&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMCATEGORY0=Digital

ACK=SetExpressCheckout API call failed.

Detailed Error Message:

Short Error Message:

Error Code:

Error Severity Code:

Has anyone experienced similar problems?

**checkout.php:**

```
<?php
require_once ("paypalfunctions.php");

$PaymentOption = "PayPal";
if ($PaymentOption == "PayPal")
{
    // ==================================
    // PayPal Express Checkout Module
    // ==================================    

    //'------------------------------------
    //' The paymentAmount is the total value of 
    //' the purchase.
    //'
    //' TODO: Enter the total Payment Amount within the quotes.
    //' example : $paymentAmount = "15.00";
    //'------------------------------------

    $paymentAmount = "15.00";

    //'------------------------------------
    //' The currencyCodeType  
    //' is set to the selections made on the Integration Assistant 
    //'------------------------------------
    $currencyCodeType = "USD";
    $paymentType = "Sale";

    //'------------------------------------
    //' The returnURL is the location where buyers return to when a
    //' payment has been succesfully authorized.
    //'
    //' This is set to the value entered on the Integration Assistant 
    //'------------------------------------
    $returnURL = "http://jquery.bunkerhill.com/php/orderconfirm.php";

    //'------------------------------------
    //' The cancelURL is the location buyers are sent to when they hit the
    //' cancel button during authorization of payment during the PayPal flow
    //'
    //' This is set to the value entered on the Integration Assistant 
    //'------------------------------------
    $cancelURL = "http://jquery.bunkerhill.com/php/cancel.php";

    //'------------------------------------
    //' Calls the SetExpressCheckout API call
    //'
    //' The CallSetExpressCheckout function is defined in the file PayPalFunctions.php,
    //' it is included at the top of this file.
    //'-------------------------------------------------

    $items = array();
    $items[] = array('name' => 'jQuery-Translator', 'amt' => $paymentAmount, 'qty' => 1);

    //::ITEMS::

    // to add anothe item, uncomment the lines below and comment the line above 
    // $items[] = array('name' => 'Item Name1', 'amt' => $itemAmount1, 'qty' => 1);
    // $items[] = array('name' => 'Item Name2', 'amt' => $itemAmount2, 'qty' => 1);
    // $paymentAmount = $itemAmount1 + $itemAmount2;

    // assign corresponding item amounts to "$itemAmount1" and "$itemAmount2"
    // NOTE : sum of all the item amounts should be equal to payment  amount 

    $resArray = SetExpressCheckoutDG( $paymentAmount, $currencyCodeType, $paymentType, 
                                            $returnURL, $cancelURL, $items );
    $ack = strtoupper($resArray["ACK"]);
    if($ack == "SUCCESS" || $ack == "SUCCESSWITHWARNING")
    {
            $token = urldecode($resArray["TOKEN"]);
            RedirectToPayPalDG( $token );
    } 
    else  
    {
            //Display a user friendly Error on the page using any of the following error information returned by PayPal
            $ErrorCode = urldecode($resArray["L_ERRORCODE0"]);
            $ErrorShortMsg = urldecode($resArray["L_SHORTMESSAGE0"]);
            $ErrorLongMsg = urldecode($resArray["L_LONGMESSAGE0"]);
            $ErrorSeverityCode = urldecode($resArray["L_SEVERITYCODE0"]);

            echo "SetExpressCheckout API call failed. " . "<br/>";
            echo "Detailed Error Message: " . $ErrorLongMsg . "<br/>";
            echo "Short Error Message: " . $ErrorShortMsg . "<br/>";
            echo "Error Code: " . $ErrorCode . "<br/>";
            echo "Error Severity Code: " . $ErrorSeverityCode . "<br/>";
    }
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must be getting a blank response back from PayPal, which means you're probably getting a curl error, which means you're probably running into the SSLv3 handshake failure that PayPal just flipped the switch with on 1/19/16.

This is something PayPal did because of the [POODLE vulnerability](https://www.angelleye.com/php-curl-sslv3-vulnerability/).

What you should do is check for curl error to verify this is the problem you're running into (I can almost guarantee it because we're seeing a whole lot of it since they flipped the switch.)

Then, the easiest thing to do is contact your web host and explain that you're running into this problem and they need to update your server to fix it.  It basically comes down to the server stack of software, specifically OpenSSL, getting updated to supported versions that handle TLS fallback correctly.

Comment: Here is the response from my web-hosting provider: As you may understand - it's impossible for us to enable it since we just can't jeopardize the security of our customers that are using the same shared server with affected domain that would be using SSL v3.0. So I recommend you to modify your connection scripts so they would use some other connection protocols, like TLS 1.0, TLS 1.1 for example. Or please try checking for possible workarounds with your developer in this case.  Please advise.

Comment: Here is an update from the hoster - can you please provide the exact requirements for the software installed on server? For example - necessary OpenSSL version that's required in this case. Or please provide the error messages related to SSL you are getting in this case so we would use these for the further investigation of this matter.

Comment: Forcing it in your code is a work-around that isn't the best solution.  The server stack should be falling back to the compatible protocol on its own.  I just tell people to get updated to the latest versions and that fixes it.  I have yet to pin point exactly which versions resolve the problem, but there is lots of info about it out there.

Comment: I checked the curl response and it is blank. This is the final response from the web host company (IX):  I regret to inform you that unfortunately we can not update the servers at
the present moment due to shared hosting environment. Nevertheless, Ron,
 I've set this ticket to on-hold as we are awaiting for reply regarding the
 OpenSSL version that's required and the exact error messages related to SSL you are getting. Is there a work-around for this issue?

Comment: I guess the work-around would be to find a new host that isn't using software from 10+ years ago.  ;)

Comment: The answer here provides some good detail:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35094436/curl-php-sslv3-error-and-cant-get-tls-to-work

Comment: I am in the process of moving my sites to GoDaddy and am happy to add this issue is resolved. However, I am now having a problem with " RedirectToPayPalDG", that is it is not redirecting. I know the Url and token are correct because I can enter them into a browser and the redirection works. Let me know if you have any insights into this problem. Perhaps I should start a new question?